# How do I get the information typed into a TextBox?

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, enter

I want to utilize the information typed into a TextBox in the future part of
this program. This program sets it all up in a form and when I type
something into the textbox and press the Enter key, it goes to line 32, the
`Console.WriteLine`, correctly and shows the quoted part "do calculations
here" but not the value, txtFolder, typed inside the TextBox.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MainForm : Form {

  private TextBox txtFolder;

  // set up the window
  public MainForm() {
    InitializeComponents();
  }

  private void InitializeComponents() {
    this.Text = "Textbox";
    Width = 500;

    // get textbox entry
    Label sbfldr           = new Label();
    sbfldr.Location        = new Point(10,140);
    sbfldr.Size            = new Size (315,20);
    sbfldr.Text = "Enter something into textbox and press the ENTER key";
    this.Controls.Add(sbfldr);
    TextBox txtFolder      = new TextBox();
    txtFolder.Location     = new Point(325,139);
    txtFolder.KeyUp += getFolder;
    txtFolder.Parent = this;
    this.Controls.Add(txtFolder);
  }

  private void getFolder(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
      Console.WriteLine("do calculations here "+txtFolder);
      e.Handled = true;
    }
  }

  public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      Application.Run( new MainForm() );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `txtFolder.Text` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a `TextBox` using the `Text` property:

```
string myValue = myTextBox.Text;
```

In your code, you would have this:

```
Console.WriteLine("do calculations here " + txtFolder.Text);
```

[Here is the documentation for `TextBox.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.text?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Console.WriteLine("do calculations here "+txtFolder);
```

To this:

```
Console.WriteLine("do calculations here "+txtFolder.Text);
```

Comment: Sorry, these answers did not work. Upon compile, I get the message "TextBox.cs(7,23): warning CS0649: Field 'Mainform.txtFolder' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Comment: Sounds like an unrelated problem.  Sounds like you never create a textbox control and assign it to `txtFolder.` Normally this is done in `InitializeComponent`. You might want to remove the control and add it again, using the forms designer.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the oop-related issues by changing the instances of "private" to "public"